# Will my Danish residency permit be revoked if I end my Danish researcher's position earlier and if not, will it allow me to work outside Denmark?

Tags: working-visas, eu, denmark, danish-citizens

I'm non-EU citizen doing a postdoc at a US university, and I'm not from one of the countries with a relatively strong passport. My goal is to get a job in a EU country that issues a Blue Card and eventually get myself one. I'm trying to see here if I can get closer to my goal by taking the following route: suppose I get a position as a researcher with more than 400,000 annual DKK salary. (I've good chance in getting that). By the "pay limit scheme" mentioned in https://www.justlanded.com/english/Denmark/Denmark-Guide/Visas-Permits/Residence-permits, I can get a Danish work and residency permit. However, my goal is to move outside DK and get a position in EU minus DK in the first year itself. I'd like to know how much mobility does the Danish residence card holders have.

My question is: if I terminate the job contract in before the end, will they terminate my Danish permit as well after 14 days? Or will it still be valid? In the second case, can I use this Danish permit to search for jobs, say in France?

Comment: I don't know about Denmark (hence I can't answer) but in France it would depend on the visa. My scientist visa won't be revoked if i quit my job, but then I couldn't use that job to apply for a blue card. If I were you I'd work throughout my contract and check the terms of your visa about whether you will be entitled to remain in the country after. Get the blue card during the contract. Could also work the required number of years in DK in order to naturalise which would make your life easier. That's my plan in FR. Also, not quitting job will be less harsh on your lab as well...

Comment: @lafemmecosmique Thanks! The thing about Denmark is it's one of the EU countries that doesn't issue a Blue Card(BC), which makes one point of my question. Interstingly, I had also been on a carte de sejour scientifique in France when I worked at two French universities as postdoc.

Another point of my question is mobility. Once you've a Blue Card in one EU country, it applies to all the ones that issue a BC. However, DK doesn't. So the question is, can we use the resident card in DK to search for job somewhere else? Yes, I understand the less harsh part, but (contd.)

Comment: @lafemmecosmique (contd.) ...but BC and work permits being hard to get from outside (when one doesn't have a visa in EU anymore), I've to take a somewhat harsh but legal action to execute my plan to get back at EU issuing BC.

Now, if this helps you in future since I've been in scientific visa as well: you correctly said that you can't use your carte de sejour to get a BC, your scientific salary in France, with a high probability won't meet the minimum earning requirement (around 53331€ gross/year). But you can search for a job locally and if you get that, (contd)

Comment: @lafemmecosmique (contd)...this'll solve your work permit problem. Now, if you don't get a job immediately, you go to Pôle Emploi in your arrondissement/code postale, and register asap after your scientific contracts finishes. It takes them at least a month or two to start your chomage(unemployment benefits), which ANYONE with a French income is eligible for. That's what I did when I took a vacation after my French work finished and before coming to the US. Pôle Emploi will also help you to look for jobs, give you training for FREE, even if you're non EU citizen.

Comment: Why not look for a job (e.g. in Germany but even in France) from Denmark? It seems all around safer from a legal standpoint, you would have more money and more time to find it and your application would look stronger if you are currently employed. Obviously, employers could prefer local candidates but if you want a Blue Card, you have to target technical or managerial jobs requiring high qualifications anyway and in that case being a few hundred kilometers away should not be a deal breaker.

Comment: @Gala Thanks! I'm employed at a US university as a postdoc (temporary researcher with a PhD), and the Danish researcher job I'm eyeing at is also a postdoc. I've high scientific skills which probably would fall in the "shortage job" category. 

My current job in the US is valid till next February, and also renewable with a high probability, so time isn't a matter. Denmark will pay me more for sure. 

But let me understand you: did you say it's safer legally to look for a job in Denmark? Why if I may ask? I understand I'll be in EU, but would it matter much? (contd.)

Comment: @Gala Also, do you know if my Danish permit be revoked if I terminate my  postdoc position? If not, would it be any advantage to look for job in a EU country that issues Blue Card? Thanks!

Comment: It's safer because there would be no doubt about the fact that you reside in Denmark and no risk that your permit could be revoked. If you leave your job, you might still keep your permit for some time (or not, I don't know) but you cannot in any case reside in another EU country (or travel elsewhere in the Schengen area for more than 90 days). If you don't have a job and leave Denmark for good, it might appear that you are doing just that and you only have 90 days to find another status...

Comment: By contrast, sending out resumes while living in Denmark is obviously not illegal and even short trips to Germany or elsewhere for an interview are completely fine. So there is nothing preventing you from seeking a job in a Blue Card country. Whatever strategy you use, you are definitely not allowed to work in another EU country and would have to apply for the card after finding a position.

Comment: Thanks again! In the link I gave in the question, it says the residence card will be revoked after 14 days the contract finish, but it doesn't say anything about what happens if I terminate the contract. I'll not leave Denmark without having another job. But I know that getting a Blue Card is long process. So I was wondering if I can use the Danish residency permit to work say in France? It seems from your comment the answer is no?

Comment: @Gala But in the worst case I don't find a job after my Danish contract expires, I'll still have some time to apply and get a new job outside Denmark, right? Thanks!

Comment: @Mathmath No you cannot do that. That's the point of the Blue Card: Once you have it, you can start working in another Blue Card country while your application is being processed, with regular permit, you always have to wait for the end of the procedure before starting to work.